# Как учесть несколько событий

Tags: jquery

Нужно чтобы это скрипт выполнялся по нажатию на кнопки клавиатуры и по кликах мышью, как прикрутить сюда еще одно событие? Клики мышью.

```
$('.letter_mytext').keyup(function(event){
    var myText = $(this).val();
    $('.preview_content #'+prbId).html(myText);
});
```

Comment: `$('.letter_mytext').bind('keyup click',`

Comment: bind устарел...

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

`$('.letter_mytext').on("keyup click", function(event){...`

Comment: Угу, я чет протупил, сделал так уже .bind('keyup click'